# Assembly Bootloader prints nothing at all

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bootloader

I am trying to output the hexadecimal value stored in dx register in my boot sector program.It outputs nothing at all.NOT even `Booting from Hard disk` as usual.

My code:

boot_sect.asm

```
mov ah,0x0e ; TELE TYPE MODE
org 0x7c00 ;use when address of label is used
mov bx,HELLO
mov dx,0x1fb7
call print_bx
call print_dx

jmp $
%include "print_dx_hex.asm";function print_hex value in dx 
    
HELLO:
    db 'Hello World',0
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

print_dx_hex.asm

```
print_dx:
    pusha
    mov bx,HEX_OUT+5
    jmp INIT
CONT:
    dec bx
    shr dx,4
    cmp dx,0x0000
    jne INIT
    mov bx,HEX_OUT
    call print_bx
    popa 
    ret
INIT:
    mov ax,0x000f
    and ax,dx
    mov [bx],al
    jmp CONT

%include "print_bx.asm"

HEX_OUT:
    db "0x0000",0
```

print_bx.asm

```
print_bx:
    pusha
    call printing_loop
    mov al,0xa ; GOES TO
    int 0x10 ; NEW LINE
    mov al,0xd ; CARRIAGE
    int 0x10 ; RETURN
    popa
    ret
    
printing_loop:
    mov al,[bx]
    int 0x10
    add bx,0x01
    cmp byte [bx],0x00 ; LOOP TO ITERATE
    jne printing_loop ; THROUGH THE STRING
    ret
```

The `print_bx` works perfectly(tested with previous code).

1)Why is the code not working?

2)Why is it complete blank instead of a compiling error or wrong value?

3)How can I use a debugger with qemu to find the error on my own?

Comment: The numbers `0x0..0xF` and the digits `'0'..'F'` are not the same values. After you isolate the current nibble you'll have to convert it into the corresponding digit.

Comment: @Michael How to make that conversion?Should I use ASCII charts??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code misses the hexadecimal translation between the numbers 0 to 15 and the characters "0" to "9" and "A" to "F".

An easy solution is to use the `XLATB` instruction that literally translates the value in the `AL` register by the value found in memory at the address obtained from adding the `BX` and `AL` registers.

Below is a solution for your program, some remarks though:

- The BIOS.Teletype function 0Eh expects you to pass the desired video page in the `BH` register and if the video mode is a graphic one even the desired color in the `BL` register. Therefore, you should never use `BX` as your string pointer. I have used `SI` as the string pointer.
- Your bootloader uses the `ORG 7C00h` directive and should setup the `DS` segment register accordingly to `DS=0`. You cannot rely on BIOS for this!

```
ORG 0x7C00

xor  ax, ax
mov  ds, ax
mov  si, HELLO
mov  dx, 0x1FB7
call print_si
call print_dx

jmp $

print_dx:
    pusha
    mov  bx, HEX_TABLE
    mov  si, HEX_OUT+5
    jmp  INIT
CONT:
    dec  si
    shr  dx, 4
    cmp  dx, 0
    jne  INIT
    mov  si, HEX_OUT
    call print_si
    popa 
    ret
INIT:
    mov  al, dl
    and  al, 15
    xlatb
    mov  [si], al
    jmp  CONT

HEX_OUT:
    db "0x0000", 0
HEX_TABLE:
    db "0123456789ABCDEF"

print_si:
    pusha
    mov  bx, 0x0007      ; VideoPage=0 Color=7 (White)
    mov  ah, 0x0E        ; BIOS.Teletype
    call printing_loop
    mov  al, 13
    int  0x10
    mov  al, 10
    int  0x10
    popa
    ret
    
printing_loop:
    mov  al, [si]
    int  0x10
    inc  si
    cmp  byte [si], 0
    jne  printing_loop
    ret

HELLO:
    db 'Hello World', 0
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

The above makes your program correct. I did not apply any optimizations. In case you are looking for tips, post your working code on the CodeReview forum.